# Draw a cube wire mesh in 2D with smooth corners

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to draw a rectangle wire mesh in Graphics (not Graphics3D). My attempt produces ugly corners. Is there a remedy for this problem?

```
a = {0, 0}; 
b = {2, 0};
c = {2, 1.5};
d = {0, 1.5};
g = Graphics[
  {{Black, FaceForm[None], 
    EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[8], CapForm["Round"]}], 
    Polygon[{a, b, c, d}] , Polygon[.5 + {a, b, c, d}]}, {Black, 
    FaceForm[None], 
    EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[6], CapForm["Round"]}], 
    Polygon[{a, a + .5, d + .5, d}], 
    Polygon[{c, c + .5, b + .5, b}] }}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-.5, 2.6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `Line` instead of Polygon. You won’t need FaceForm. Also, Specify the graphics directives only once, and they will apply to everything that follows.

Comment: use `JoinForm` instead of `CapForm`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

I would minimize code by different point specs, translation, and some combination of CapForm, JoinForm, and/or partitioning. All things below give visually the same result. I exaggerated a bit with thickness so you see corners remain smooth.

```
pts={{0, 0},{2, 0},{2, 1.5},{0, 1.5}};
ptsTR=TranslationTransform[{.5,.5}][pts];
th=.05;
Graphics[{Black,Thickness[th],CapForm["Round"],
    Line[Partition[pts,2,1,1]],
    Line[Partition[ptsTR,2,1,1]],
    Line[Transpose[{pts,ptsTR}]]
}]

pts={{0, 0},{2, 0},{2, 1.5},{0, 1.5},{0, 0}};
ptsTR=TranslationTransform[{.5,.5}][pts];
th=.05;
Graphics[{
    Black,Thickness[th],CapForm["Round"],JoinForm["Round"],
    Line[pts],Line[ptsTR],Line[Transpose[{pts,ptsTR}]]
}]

pts={{0, 0},{2, 0},{2, 1.5},{0, 1.5}};
ptsTR=TranslationTransform[{.5,.5}][pts];
th=.05;set=Sequence[Black,Thickness[th]];
Graphics[{
    {set,CapForm["Round"],Line[Transpose[{pts,ptsTR}]]},
    {FaceForm[],EdgeForm[{set,JoinForm["Round"]}],Polygon[pts],Polygon[ptsTR]}
}]
```